# Number of Odds and Evens in a List Function - Python

Tags: python, list, append, return-value, modulus

I am trying to create a function called "odd_even" which takes my already created list (named "nums") and determines the number of odd and even numbers, and then returns the variables to me. However when I run this code I get:

NameError: name 'odd' is not defined

How do I fix this? If you can give me any useful pointers on the "return" function that would also be greatly appreciated.

```
import random

def main():

     nums = []

     for x in range(10):

     nums.append(random.randrange(1,26))

     def odd_even(given_list):
         odd = 0
         even = 0
         for x in given_list:
             if x % 2 == 0:
                 even += 1
             else:
                 odd += 1

         return odd
         return even

     odd_even(nums)

     print("List had ", odd, "odds and ", even, "evens.")

 main()
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing 2 things wrong.

First, you are trying to `return` two values but on different lines. You cant do this, to do this, do so as a tuple:

```
def odd_even(given_list):
     odd = 0
     even = 0
     for x in given_list:
         if x % 2 == 0:
             even += 1
         else:
             odd += 1

     return odd, even
```

Second, you call the function but dont store the value(s) of `return`. So you need change:

`odd_even(nums)` to `odd, even = odd_even(nums)`

By trying to execute:

`print("List had ", odd, "odds and ", even, "evens.")`

The `main()` is looking for variables `odd` and `even`, but they dont exist in `main()`, they exist locally in `odd_even()` (hence why you are calling `return` as to *return them to the calling function*. The reason you only see an error with respect to `odd` is because it is the first variable in that `print()` that the interpreter encounters an error on.

The only way around this without correct use of `return` is to declare them as `global`. But that is a bad idea so don't do that, keep things local on the stack!

Answer (score 0):

You have some syntactic errors. Python...unlike many programming languages is whitespace conscious. This means you need to be careful with your indentation and spacing. More traditional languages like Java and C use brackets {} to define a scope, and semicolons ; to figure out line termination.

Perhaps you copied it poorly, but from what I see, it appears as though you are defining the function odd_even() within the function main(). That is, the definition of odd_even() is tabbed to the right, which means that its definition is within the function main. I assume that you want main to call the function odd_even(). Thus, you must tab it back over to the left so that it is at the same indentation level as main().

For this reason I use horizontal lines (see below) to clearly outline the scope of functions. This is good for me when I write in Python because otherwise it can be very unclear where one function ends, and where another begins.

Also, it appears as though you have 2 return statements. If you want to return 2 values, you should encompass it within an object. To get around this, there are two simple solutions that come to mind. You can make the odd_even() function access global variables (not recommended)...or you can return an array (any number of values back) or a tuple (exactly 2, but this is python specific).

Below is an implementation of both:

```
import random

# Declare global variables outside the scope of any function
odd = 0
even = 0

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

def main():

    nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

    return_value = odd_even(nums)

    # Get the individual values back
    o = return_value[0]
    e = return_value[1]

    # You can use the global variables
    print("List had ", odd, "odds and ", even, "evens.")


    # Or you can get the array back
    print("List had ", o, "odds and ", e, "evens.")


#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

def odd_even(given_list):

    # This means we are referencing the variables odd and even that are global
    global odd
    global even

    # Loop through the array
    for x in given_list:
        if x % 2 == 0:
            even += 1
        else:
            odd += 1

    return [odd, even]
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------


main()
```

Comment: This is all incorrect information. Python supports a user defined `main()` unlike C/C++/Java which have a `main`. Python also supports the return of multiple values (as a `tuple`) as has done so for many versions. Beyond that, declaring variables as `global` should be seldom done; especially where there is a way to do so locally, which there is here.

Comment: I am not saying anything about main...I am saying that they cannot define a function odd_even() WITHIN the function main(). So provided that the function odd_even() is tabbed over...the python interpreter is finding a function definition (hence the keyword def) within another function main()...

I did mention tuples as an option...

"... or a tuple (exactly 2, but this is python specific)."

Comment: To say "not permitted" but then provide a valid use of the language is a contradiction. You should update your post accordingly.

Comment: You can absolutely define a  nested function as to not take up space in global definitions.

Comment: Well, you probably know better than I do. Thanks for the insight